# How to Apply Dynamic Bookmark

Tags: powerbi-desktop, bookmarks

i have Page A and Page B.
Page B is the Drill Through View of page A.

Page A is having two Bookmark x and y.
PAge B is having two bookmark x' and y'

If Drill through used for page A with Bookmark x, then page B with Bookmark x' should be display

Similarly if Drill through used for page A with Bookmark y, then page B with Bookmark y' should be display

Page A is having two Bookmark x and y.
PAge B is having two bookmark x' and y'

If Drill through used for page A with Bookmark x, then page B with Bookmark x' should be display

Similarly if Drill through used for page A with Bookmark y, then page B with Bookmark y' should be display